# Print first few elements of a list in perl

Tags: perl

Have a next perl code

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

#make some random numbers
my @list = map { rand } 1..10;

say "print all 10 numbers";
say $_ for @list;

say "print only first 5";
my $n=0;
for (@list) {
        say $_ if $n++ < 5;
}
```

some more compact form for printing first (last) N elements of any array?

the next is syntax error...

```
$n=0;
#say $_ if($n++ < 5) for @list;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To print the first 5 items:

```
say for @list[0 .. 4];
```

To print the last 5 items:

```
say for @list[-5 .. -1];
```

Comment: For more details, see `perldoc perldata` and search for /Slices/ http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Comment: Note that if `@list` has fewer than 5 elements, the first  one will create them (so the  `@list` will have 5 elements some of which `undef` afterwards) and the second will fail with an error.

Comment: How do I get max 5 elements from the start instead of adding undef if there aren't 5 elements in the array?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @list = map { int(rand*10) } 1..10;
print join(', ', @list[0..4]) . "\n";
```

Also, `use strict`, without exception, unless you really enjoy spending far too much time hunting down subtle scoping bugs.

Comment: I think the `use 5.012` pragma imports `strict` by default, but good point nonetheless.

Comment: @squiguy [Better to make it explicit](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=864234), especially since `use 5.012` not only prevents the script from running under an older Perl whether or not there's actually anything in it which was new with 5.12, but [actually prevents users of older Perls from easily seeing what in the script doesn't work under their version](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=864292).

Comment: Good point. My first two lines of every script include `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: @AaronMiller The second link apparently doesn't know what `use 5.010;` does, since the code in question wouldn't compile without it.  And, no, it is not better to have a long list of boilerplate at the top.  If there is going to be boilerplate, make it as minimal as possible.

Comment: @darch Which link; how so?

Comment: @AaronMiller `perl -e 'say "Hi!";'`

Comment: @darch Go figure; I've never seen much use for Perl's answer to Pascal `writeln`, nor do I feel confident using a switch statement whose documentation says "don't trust this", and I frequently deploy Perl code on hosts with Perls as old as 5.8. So I've never actually had cause to trip over that.

Comment: @Nemo *De gustibus non disputandum*, of course, but I would point out that economy of vertical space, at the expense of clarity, is often a difficult decision to justify.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write it with a `while` loop instead.

```
my $i = 0;
say $list[$i++] while $i < 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, a destructive approach:

```
splice @list, 5;
say for @list;
```